# Evaluating numbers that include thousand separators

Tags: javascript

I understand that if the parseFloat function encounters any character other than numeric characters (0-9+-. and exponents) it just evaluates the number up to that character, discarding anything else.

I'm having a problem where I need to be able to validate numbers with thousand separators like so:

```
var number = "10,000.01"; //passes
var numberWithoutThousand = "10000.01"; //fails

//i.e:
if(parseFloat(number) <= 10000) {
     return true;   
} 
//passess
```

problem is the above code returns true when technically that number is larger than 10,000.

What's the best way to get around this? I've considered stripping out the comma before testing the number, but not sure that is a good strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have numbers, you have strings, so just removing the comma is the way to go

```
number = number.replace(/\,/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "stripping the comma" strategy seems good to me.

```
if ( parseFloat( number.replace(",","") ) ) { etc(); }
```

Comment: Don't forget `",,".replace(",", ""); // ","`, you need a global flag on this.

Comment: @PaulS, can you explain why that's needed?

Comment: @MikeRifgin The 'g' is needed to tell replace to do the replacement _globally_, rather than just doing a single replacement. You may have a number: 100,000,000.01

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested, to have `,` in the number it must be a string and so do a search and replace. If you are having to do this on a regular basis then make yourself a reusable function.

Javascript

```
function myParseFloat(value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        value = value.replace(/,/g, '');
    }

    return parseFloat(value);
}

var number1 = "10,000.01",
    number2 = "10000.01",
    number3 = 10000.01;

console.log(myParseFloat(number1), myParseFloat(number2), myParseFloat(number3));
```

Output

```
10000.01 10000.01 10000.01
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/6RQXw/)